# Toggle Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Making a password generator website and I don't know how to allow people toggle checkboxes to choose a preference for their password.

I don't know how to allow people to toggle checkboxes more than once. I also would like to know how it to update automatically when someone checks the box.

```
<label class="input-toggle">

       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked>
        <span></span>
          </label>
```

I've been trying something like this:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
```

});

But I don't know how to make the characters longer or shorter as an option.

What I have so far: http://codepen.io/HaydnAnderson/pen/EKGxJP

Answer (score 0):

Very simple question.

https://jsfiddle.net/41vuxh44/1/

```
window.passwordGen = {
    preferences : {
    uppercase : false,
    numbers   : false
  }
};

$("#numbers").on('change', function(event)
{
    window.passwordGen.preferences.numbers = $(this).prop('checked');
  console.log(passwordGen);
});
```

In my example, I am binding a living change event to the `#numbers` checkbox. Using `on` is the new way of doing living event bindings.

When the checkbox is altered, it fires the event. I then update my global preferences object to be the value of the checked property, which is a boolean representing if the checkbox is clicked.

There's a lot more I could do with this to make my preferences object more robust. Perhaps you'd want to use the new HTML5 DOM storage to retain preferences, and then move this logic to a new global that fires also on page load. You could also conceivably move this to a general function that handles many different inputs being changed to keep code concise, but what I've given will do what you're asking for.

Comment: How can I change the password preference from the example you provided?